# Слетела кодировка

Tags: php, laravel

Всем привет, слетела кодировка, почта была создана на хостинге ps.kz Помогите плиз. Саппорт сказали добавить utf-8. 
Вот код:

```
public function form()
{
    $this ->validate(request(), [
        'name'=>'required',
        'phone'=>'required',
    ]);

    $message = "Name: ".request('name')."\nPhone:"
    .request('phone');
    $subject = "Form from test.kz";
    $headers = 'From: info@test.kz' . "\r\n" .
        'Reply-To: info@test.kz' . "\r\n".
        'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

        mail('test@test.kz', $subject, $message, $headers);

    // return response()->json(['msg' => request()->all()]);
    return view('pages.start');
}
```

Вот что получаю:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Тебе в переменную `$headers` необходимо добавить кодировку:

```
$headers .= 'Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n";
```

Источник:
https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.mail.php